# Travelling with someone to the UK

Tags: visas, uk, international-travel, family

I'm filling my application at the official [visa4uk](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/welcome) site. I have plans for my family including my wife and kids joining me later

Regarding the question are you travelling with anyone should I mention them?
And if my wife is filling her application, as regards the same question, should she mention me or just the kids?

Comment: Which visa application? Tourist? What is your nationality?

Comment: @pnuts With the full domain name, it sounds quite a bit less scammy, good to know!

Comment: @pnuts I like to clarify, we've had what looked like tourist questions become turn out to be migratory ones :/

Comment: indeed, that's why I clarify :)

Comment: @pnuts, the answer is the same for tourists or any other type of visa. That section of the form is common to all applicants.  So it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 7):

If the other members are not travelling with you, you leave that section blank and go to Part 9 of the form (Additional Information) and explain that your wife and children will file applications later.  Doing this is critically important!

You would do this regardless of your nationality and regardless if you are applying as a visitor or for something else.

Give your wife your GWF number, so that she can place it on her form.  And she should place both hers and yours on the children's form.

She can annotate the children's applications like this...

```
Primary:              {your GWF number}
Accompanying Parent:  {her GWF number}
```

In summary, your wife has your GWF number and your children have both GWF numbers.  They are smart enough to understand what's going on and link everything up if they have the relevant information to do so.  Note: there is no rule governing this and the guidance does not mention this situation at all; so this answer is simply 'best practices' i.e., no relevant links to a UK site.

As pointed out in comments, your question *looks* like a non-tourist question, but fortunately the answer is the same for tourists.  If your next question has to do with working or studying in the UK, please use the [Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions) site.