# How should I answer financial questions for UK Standard Visitor visa applications for travel as a family?

Tags: uk, family, standard-visitor-visas

I am applying for a UK Standard Visitor visa with my wife and daughter.

**Is it OK to put "NA" or "N/A" for questions about the applicant's financial capacity when the applicant is a dependant?**

I have mentioned overall trip cost in my application as I will pay for entire trip.  In applications of my wife (housewife) and daughter I answered as follows:

> 1) How much do you spend each month on living costs?  **N/A**
>
> 2) How much of your total monthly income is given to your family members and other dependents? **N/A**
>
> 3) What is the cost to you personally of your trip in GBP(£)? **N/A**
>
> 4) The total amount of money you have for this trip? **N/A**
>
> 5) The cost of the airplane, boat or train tickets? **N/A**
>
> 6) The cost of your accommodation? **N/A**
>
> 7) The cost of your living expenses? **N/A**
>
> 8) Is someone other than you paying for all or a part of your trip? **Yes**
>
> 9) Please select what the relationship is of the person who is  contributing to the payment for your trip? **Father**
>
> 10) How much will they be paying towards your trip (in GBP £)? **Pay entire trip**
>
> 11) Please explain why they are paying towards the cost of your trip? 
>   **I will travel with my parents. My father will pay for entire trip.Father application Reference Number ....**
>
> 12) What is the total amount in GBP(£)? **pay entire**

Is it correct or do I need to mention each person's cost on the applications?

Comment: Hi, and welcome, what is your question about your application? What in your answers are you not satisfied with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You and your family are applying for a Standard Visitor Visa and you are the primary.  Other family members are relying on your sponsorship and so they are entering "N/A" in the relevant fields. You want to know if it's OK.

This is fine. Each family member should provide your GWF number in the remarks area.  There are some details on the same subject here: [Travelling with someone to the UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52474/travelling-with-someone-to-the-uk) that you can use as a reference point.

Remember also that only the primary should submit evidence, they do not want to see lots of paperwork for dependants because it goes against their overarching policy that evidence should be *originals*.